# Count function for two variables in SQL Report Builder 2.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report-builder2.0

I would like to display a simple COUNT for a variable but with a conditon that another variable is filtered. This is how I could imagine the function, but I can't make it work in Report Builder. I am not using a graph/table which is why I can't use for example the Tablix filter function. I simply want to display the value in a textbox, so I only can only define the function. Should look somehow like this:

```
= COUNT(Fields!<var1>) IF (Fields!<var2> = "xyz")
```

Thankful for any suggestions!!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use Iif function along with count something like this...

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!FieldName.Value="xyz",1,0))
```

or

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!FieldName.Value="xyz",1,Nothing))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback! But the solution you suggest would only allow me to filter on the values of ONE attribute. 

I would like to combine a filter for two attributes. For example: 

var a = 5; var b = 6

sort of like this: COUNTIF((var a = 5) & (var b = 6))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
    =COUNT( IIF( Fields!VarA.Value=5, IIF(Fields!VarB.Value=6, 1, 0), 0)
```

This will check if VarA = 5, then if VarB = 6, will count 1, else 0.